# Is there a way to run GetAllUsers against multiple MembershipProviders?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

I have support for both 'local' accounts provided by the `SqlMembershipProvider` and Active Directory accounts provided by the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` in my application.

I need to have centralised user management so need to combine the user lists from both. the `Membership` class includes `GetAllUsers`, but this seems to only query the default provider (in my case AD), and requires pagination.

Is there a way to query both membership providers and return the list from both, ideally performing the pagination that is required to query the AD provider automatically?

The only other solution I can think of is to manually query both and somehow merge the lists, but I think that would have lots of edge cases with making sure the pagination works correctly in the queries as I would need to paginate both sources separately.

**Update**: Having thought more about this, I'm not sure it is possible (without a massive performance hit and complexity increase), and because of I doubt there is an API in .NET to do it. If there is it would save me a lot of work so I'd still like to know, but for now I'll try and work around the issue.

Comment: Build a custom `Membership`-provider and implement your own `Membership.GetAllUsers` method. An easy approach would be to inherit from `SqlMembershipProvider` and concat the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`-users there.

Comment: Doesn't that violate the 'level of abstraction' of a MembershipProvider though? Maybe that's not the best wording for it, but I would have thought the providers are essentially supposed to be a set rather than a tree or graph.

Comment: Also, that would still have the same issues with merging the results of calling GetAllUsers on both of the other two providers, and so there doesn't seem to be any benefit in turning that into a MembershipProvider.